# OpenGraph API Beta: publish_action vs publish_stream

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph, beta

Today, Facebook announced an entirely new way to share user actions on your site on through your app. [The documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/) is a good attempt at explaining how things work, but if I hadn't already built a sophisticated app off the existing OpenGraph API, I would probably be lost.

What's not made clear, at all, is what happens to the "old" permissions. Facebook wants us to prompt our users for the publish_action permission. I *assume* I can start (or can I not start yet? not clear here when this is usable on my live site) passing publish_action as a permission in my getLoginUrl (PHP SDK) call immediately.

What happens to the now "old" publish_stream permission? Do I need both? Will publish_stream be fazed out? Can already granted publish_stream permissions be translated in to publish_action so I don't have to prompt all my users for a new permission and scare them away? How do I future proof my app? What about that SPAM algorithm Facebook unleashed on app devs a few months ago, killing people's apps because they were "abusing" the publishing mechanism... does that exist for these new actions? Is there any guidance on how not to upset the algorithm gods and get banned?

I realize the new API was only just announced a few hours ago, but these are important questions and I seriously doubt I'm the only one that has them. I'd love to hear some feedback on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start testing publish_actions today, but shouldn't be asking users for it yet in your production apps until open graph launches more broadly.

publish_stream will continue to exist for more explicit posts, but we encourage apps to use open graph for Timeline apps.

Comment: I added publish_actions to my permissions so our facebook testers can try our Open Graph feature. However, that permission is not being asked on the auth dialog. My guess is its because our app is not a game. When will publish_actions be enabled for apps or at least how do we enable it just for our testers? Thanks.

Comment: i have same issue. the new timeline stuff seems buggy. e.g. the "Add to my timeline" link they provide in the docs opens aopup and then closes it. And then maybe sometimes it will actually show the permissions screen...

Comment: Be sure to add open graph verbs or similar to your app prior to requesting the publish_actions permission, otherwise it seems to be ignored.

Comment: @eggie5: I had to remove the app from my account to get the dialog to open and stay open.